# How to check if two files are the same,when one of them is in a web server?

Tags: vb.net, web, server, filestream

I am trying to make a game launcher that should be able to patch the game file if the game file and the other game file on the web server don't match.

To compare the files I could compare the size of both of them but I need a way to cast a file from web to a FileStream instance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly it is not practical to download the file from the web server every time you want to check if your local file is the same as the one online. Thats what checksum are for.

All you have to do is hash your local file and compare the checksum with the one from the server, that is provided somewhere along with the file itself, like `file.sha1` containing the 160-bits SHA-1 hash of the file.

However this operation is usually done only when you want to perform a full integrity check of your local files. Usually, updates and such are done simply by keeping track of the game version. Have a file containing a list of all updates, their respective versions and the package name that should be downloaded to update to that version. Provide update packages containing the modified files for each update you release, so the game launcher can download and install them in order to keep the game up to date.

Comment: Is there any other way (other than keeping track of the game version too) than creating another file that contains the hash of the file/Can I use the URL directly with a CRC and compare the files by reading the CRC as a string instance?

Comment: You can save the checksum in any format you like. It can be a database entry, or can be in a big file with all game files and their respective checksums or whatever. What does not make sense, is sending this CRC with a URL. The server doesn't have to know your local file checksum, its irrelevant for it, there is nothing it can do for you with that information.

Comment: No no, I am not trying to send the CRC to a web server, what I ask is that if I can use the URL directly (as if using the file from a directory in my computer) when getting the CRC from the file (the one located inside the web server)

Comment: I couldn't work out the CRC thing and it seems like keeping track of the version is a better way to do this, I got it working by creating a subkey in the registry which keeps the version and when it doesn't match with the one in the website the launcher patches the game, thanks for the help!